# Unable to resolve why ? angularjs ng-inlclude is comming commented on view through google inspector

Tags: angularjs

The original source As I want to use ng-include for various html file. But not working when looked by chrome inspector.

```
enter code here
```

```js
model.js

angular.module('pratap',[] ).controller('amarSingh', function($scope){

  $scope.element='F';


 }) ;

cntrl.js

angular.module('pratap').controller('amarSingh', function($scope){

  $scope.element='Suryavanshi';
  $scope.xpose='Kunwar pratap'


 }) ;

modules.js

angular.module('pratap',[] );

udaysingh.js

angular.module('pratap').controller('udaysingh', function($scope){

  $scope.element='Mahrana';
  $scope.xpose='Kunwar pratap singh'


 }) ;
```

```html
<!doctype html5>
<html lang="en" ng-app="pratap">
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<title>
Aglualr Apps By Maharna Pratap
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ng" ng-controller="amarSingh">
 {{element + xpose}}

</div>
<div ng-controller="udaysingh">
 {{element + xpose}}
</div>


<p >Registration</p>
<div class="Registro">


<div ng-include="regStart.html"></div>
<div ng-include="credentail.html"></div>
<div ng-include="perosnal.html"></div>
<div ng-include="review.html"></div>


</body>
<script src="module.js" ></script>
<script src="cntrl.js" ></script>
<script src="models.js" ></script>
<script src="udaysingh.js"></script>
</html>
  
  Another File regstart.html
  
  <form method="post">
<span >User name</span><input type="text" required placeholder="Ex: Maharana pratap" autocomplete="off" maxlength="30"> 
<span > Email</span><input type="text" id="email" required placeholder="Ex:pratap@mewad.com" autocomplete="off" maxlength="45">
<span >Password</span><input type="password" name="password" id="password" required placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"> 
    
    Another file credentail.html
    
    <span class="fontawesome-user"></span><input type="tel" required placeholder="Ex: 8930068008" autocomplete="off" maxlength="11" id="mobile"> 
<span class="fontawesome-envelope-alt"></span><input type="date" id="dob" required placeholder="Ex:10/10/1990" autocomplete="off" maxlength="15">
 another file personal.hmtl
    <span class="fontawesome-user"></span><input type="email" required placeholder="Ex: alternate eemail" autocomplete="off" maxlength="30"> 
<span class="fontawesome-envelope-alt"></span><input type="radio"  >
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked   > Male
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"> Female
<span class="fontawesome-lock"></span><input type="text" name="country" id="country" required placeholder="country" autocomplete="off"> 
    Anorher file review.html
    
     Name:{{uname}}</br> 
  Email: {emailid}}</br>
  Mobile No: {{mobile}}</br>
  D.O.B. : {{dob}}
  Alternate email: {{emaila}}
  Gender: {{gender}}
  Country:{{country}}
  

<input type="submit" value="Register" title="Registration">
```

But Not showing result desired commented ng-include in inspector or browser source.

the chrome source

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="pratap" class="ng-scope"><head><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<title>
Aglualr Apps By Maharna Pratap
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ng" ng-controller="amarSingh" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
 SuryavanshiKunwar pratap

</div>
<div ng-controller="udaysingh" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
 MahranaKunwar pratap singh
</div>


<p>Registration</p>
<div class="Registro">


<!-- ngInclude: regStart.html -->
<!-- ngInclude: credentail.html -->
<!-- ngInclude: perosnal.html -->
<!-- ngInclude: review.html -->



<script src="module.js"></script>
<script src="cntrl.js"></script>
<script src="models.js"></script>
<script src="udaysingh.js"></script>
</div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ng-include directive is expecting to receive a string as a file name. Check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZKvkCAru5H7QPwaNxv5B) plunkr.You just miss the single quotes around files names to include.
Like this:

```
<div ng-include="'review.html'"></div>
```

Comment: @kanwarak was the answer helpful? If yes, please mark it as the right answer for future references.